# Python OpenCV how to display 2d array of 8bit grayscale pixels

Tags: python, image, opencv, embedded

The goal is receiving an 160x120 array of 8bit grayscale pixels over serial port and showing them as an image.

I'm okay with the first part, but I wasn't able to find how to convert this 2d array of pixels to something what cv2 can display.

```
dataArray = serial.read(160*120)
frame[[0 for x in range(160)] for y in range(120)]

for i in range(0, 120):
 for j in range(0, 160):
  frame[i][j] = dataArray[j + (160 * i)]
```

So after that I have a frame to display, but no matter what I failed.

The thing is that due to lack of free memory on the transmiting side, the image is bound to be 8bit gratscale

Comment: Assuming `dataArray` is a `bytes` object, then you simply convert this to a numpy array and reshape it to proper dimensions: `image = np.frombuffer(dataArray, np.uint8).reshape(120,160)`. That's it.

Comment: Hello, please indicate what you have tried and post possible error tracebacks (as text)

Comment: Using `image = np.frombuffer(dataArray, np.uint8).reshape(120,160)` makes the frame being displayed twice in it's width and 1/2 of height